# "Video can't be played" from expansion files, only on Nexus 7

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have expansion files containing 3 videos. The videos play fine outside of the expansion files and inside on the Galaxy S3 and Asus Transformer (Android 4.0.3).

However I get "video cannot be played" on a Nexus 7 (original) using the same code when playing the videos from the expansion file. I have tried playing the videos outside the expansion file on the default media player and they play fine.

The only difference for the Nexus 7 is the fact it runs Android 4.3 and it has no external storage compared to the other devices.